# C3520 parameter pack must be expanded - incorrect behaviour for 'variadic using'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-templates

While compiling the code below with Qt 5.12 using Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 15.9.28307.1300 (amd64) and c++17 standard I get the following error:

> error C3520: 'Args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
> note: see reference to class template instantiation
> 'Helper<Args...>' being compiled

```
template<typename T> 
struct Base { 
    void operator()(const T& arg){} 
}; 

template <typename... Args>
class Helper : Base<Args>... {
public:
    using Base<Args>::operator()...;
};
```

Is this a bug with msvc? Is there any known workaround? The same code compiles on macOS using clang.

Comment: You should include the definition of `Base` ...

Comment: perhaps a bug, newer versions of mscv compile it without issues https://godbolt.org/z/sb3Kh9Kx7

Comment: class Base is defined right above the attached snippet.
template<typename T>
class Base {
    void operator()(const T& arg){...}
};

Comment: I tried to add the missing piece, but as I cannot reproduce the error (with newer msvc versions) you should please check that the code now in the question really does produce the error

Comment: Using godbolt, I had to go back to msvc 19.22 to reproduce the issue. Since 19.23 (VS 2019 version 16.3), there is no longer an error. VS 15.9 is a rather old version, I think that's VS 2017?

Comment: @ChrisMM yes it is VS 2017. I am not sure if Qt 5.12 would work with newer VS.

Comment: is Vs2017 support that C++17 feature?

Comment: ***I am not sure if Qt 5.12 would work with newer VS.*** It does work with Visual Studio 2019. Although I have not tried the current VS 2019. I use an older community version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround to variadic `using` (C++17), you might use the recursive way:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Helper;

template <>
class Helper<>
{
};

template <typename T>
class Helper<T> : Base<T>
{
public:
    using Base<T>::operator();
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class Helper<T, Ts...> : Base<T>, Helper<Ts...>
{
public:
    using Base<T>::operator();
    using Helper<Ts...>::operator();
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4qfxqY4YW)